# Breaking the row after a size of the window when nested tables in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am very new to XSLT. I have got an issue to break the lines into new row when the maximum size of window reaches,
Here is the structure of XSLT:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- Style RSS so that it is readable. -->
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:dns="Service.V1">

  <!-- Translated Parameters -->


  <!-- Context Parameters, set by calling application, no translation  -->


  <xsl:template match='/'>
    <xsl:apply-templates select='dns:Result'/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match='dns:Result'>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select='$PageTitle' />
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
          .LegendTitle
          {
          font-family: Verdana;


          }
          .ReportHeading
          {
          font-family: Verdana;
          font-size: 12pt;

          }
          .HeaderRight
          {
          color: black;
          font-family: Verdana;

          }
          .HeaderLeft
          {
          color: black;
          font-family: Verdana;
          font-size: 10pt;
          line-height: 11pt;

          }
          .HeaderLabel
          {
          color: black;
          font-family: Verdana;
          font-size: 10pt;
          line-height: 11pt;
          }
          .HeaderDataLeft
          {
          color: black;
          font-family: Verdana;
          }
          .HeaderDataRight
          {
          color: black;
          font-family: Verdana;
          }
          .MsgColHeaderCenter
          {
          color: black;
          font-family: Verdana;
          }
          .MsgColHeaderLeft
          {
          color: black;
          font-family: Verdana;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 10pt;
          }
          .MsgDataLeft
          {
          color: black;
          font-family: Verdana;
          }
          .MsgDataCenter
          {
          color: black;
          font-family: Verdana;
          font-size: 10pt;
          }
          .DetailHeader
          {
          color: black;
          }
          .DetailData
          {
          color: black;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body width="100%">
        <table cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
          <tr>
            <td width='100%' class="ReportHeading">
              <xsl:value-of select="$DocumentTitle"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <P/>
        <fieldset>
          <legend class="LegendTitle">
            <xsl:value-of select='$HeaderLabel' />
          </legend>
          <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>

          </table>
          <P/>
          <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>

          </table>
        </fieldset>
        <P/>
        <P/>

        <table width='100%' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0' border='border'>
          <tr>
            <td valign='bottom' width='150' colspan='2'   class="DetailHeader">
              <xsl:value-of select="$A"/>
            </td>
            <xsl:if test ="$ingLimits = 'True'">
              <td valign='bottom' width='150' colspan='2'  class="DetailHeader">
                <xsl:value-of select="$A"/>
              </td>
            </xsl:if>
            <td valign='bottom' class="DetailHeader">
              <xsl:text>&#xa0;</xsl:text>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign='bottom' width='75' class="DetailHeader">
              <xsl:value-of select="$eLabel"/>
            </td>
            <td valign='bottom' width='75' class="DetailHeader">
              <xsl:value-of select="$abel"/>
            </td>
            <xsl:if test ="$gLimits = 'True'">
              <td valign='bottom' width='75' class="DetailHeader">
                <xsl:value-of select="$AeLabel"/>
              </td>
              <td valign='bottom' width='75' class="DetailHeader">
                <xsl:value-of select="$LimitsLabel"/>
              </td>
            </xsl:if>
            <td valign='bottom' class="DetailHeader">
              <xsl:value-of select="$Label"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="dns:List/dns:Information">
            <xsl:apply-templates select='.'/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
        <table id="Footer" border="0" width="95%" style="font-size: 8pt; font-family: Verdana;" align="center" >
          <tr>

          </tr>
        </table >
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dns:List/dns:Information">
    <tr>
      <td valign='top' width='75' class="DetailData">
        <xsl:value-of select="dns:dSize"/>
      </td>
      <td valign='top' width='75' class="DetailData">
        <table cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0' width='75'>
          <tr >
            <td valign='top' width='75' class='DetailData'>
              <xsl:value-of select='dns:USL' />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr >
            <td valign='top' width='75' class='DetailData'>
              <xsl:value-of select='dns:SL' />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <xsl:if test ="$its = 'True'">
        <td valign='top' width='75' class="DetailData">
          <xsl:value-of select="dns:Air"/>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
          <table cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0' width='75'>
            <tr >
              <td valign='top' width='75' class='DetailData'>
                <xsl:value-of select='dns:A' />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
              <td valign='top' width='75' class='DetailData'>
                <xsl:value-of select='dns:A' />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </xsl:if>
      <td valign='top'>
        -----------------------
        <table cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0'>
          <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="dns:ListTop/dns:ListDetail">
              <td>
                <xsl:apply-templates select='.'/>
              </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dns:ListTop/dns:ListDetail">
    <table cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0' width='75'>
      <!--<xsl:attribute name="ends-row">true</xsl:attribute>-->
      <tr>
        <td valign='top' class="DetailData" >
          Test222
          <xsl:value-of select="dns:Size1"/>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- do not process non-matching nodes!  -->
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, these are coming in the same line with the horizontal scroll bar. But when I print this document, I am not able to see the complete row in the printed document. So, I want to split this line into the new line in the main row, and display the data. I hope I am clear. Please suggest!

Below is the output i will get in one row. Each column is enclosed with a row("dns:ListTop/dns:ListDetail"). I need to split these columns. Since this  is nested with one more table and td, it is not splitting!!

[image: this is the output, this row will increase, which i want to split]

Comment: Please post a reproducible example - see: [mcve]. -- IMHO, it's best to let the browser do the line-breaking for you.

Comment: @michael.hor257k : I have edited the code. It is as is in my XSLT, just that i have changed the label and parameter information. Kindly, let me know if you need more information. Since this is the first time i am looking at XSLT, i was confused how much info i need to post here. sorry for that

Comment: You need to post enough info to enable us to reproduce your problem (and hopefully, no more). That means an example of the XML input, the XSLT stylesheet, and the expected output.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Above shared code is XSLT,and i have shared the image which is the output. I need to split that columns which is enclosed with nested tables. Sad part is i cant share the XML, since that file is too confidential. Dummy created xml is not working properly

Comment: "*Sad part is i cant share the XML, since that file is too confidential. Dummy created xml is not working properly*" Well, then there is no way I can help you. Except to suggest again to let the browser do the work for you, by using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The basic strategy is to use a recursive named template. Pass two parameters to the template: the content to be output, and the amount of data to be put in each row. In the body of your template, output the first row, and if there is any more content to be processed, then make a recursive call of your template passing the remainder of the content to be processed.

Comment: Hi, Can you please provide me the code syntax ? I have understood the context what you are saying. But i am not able achieve the same using XSLT.

Comment: Sorry, I'm happy to point you in the right direction but I don't have time to provide a free coding service; and in any case I can't possibly write XSLT to handle XML that you aren't prepared to share.